# Why are images not appearing on subitems in mfc CListView/CListCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I've created a very simple view derived from `CListView`, and I want to be able to show images on each column of my `CListView`.
 To do that I know that I have to use `LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES` and use `SetItem` to set the Image in the sub item, simple as that, but not working.

all the code is here

```
void MyListView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CListView::OnInitialUpdate();

    //create the list control
    GetListCtrl().ModifyStyle(0,LVS_REPORT | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP);
    GetListCtrl().ModifyStyleEx(0,LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES);
    GetListCtrl().InsertColumn(0, _T("Column 1"), LVCFMT_LEFT,60);
    GetListCtrl().InsertColumn(1, _T("Column 2"), LVCFMT_LEFT,60);

    //load the images
    CImageList *pImageList;
    pImageList = new CImageList();
    pImageList->Create( 26,26, ILC_MASK | ILC_COLOR16,2, 2);

    CBitmap bitmap;
    bitmap.LoadBitmap(  IDB_MAIN);
    pImageList->Add( &bitmap, (COLORREF)0xFFFFFF);
    bitmap.DeleteObject();

    bitmap.LoadBitmap( IDB_MAIN1);
    pImageList->Add( &bitmap, (COLORREF)0xFFFFFF);
    bitmap.DeleteObject();
    GetListCtrl().SetImageList( pImageList, LVSIL_SMALL);
    GetListCtrl().SetImageList( pImageList, LVSIL_NORMAL);
    GetListCtrl().SetImageList( pImageList, LVSIL_STATE);
    GetListCtrl().SetImageList( pImageList, LVSIL_GROUPHEADER);

    COLORREF col;
    col = RGB(240,240,240);
    GetListCtrl().SetBkColor(col);
    GetListCtrl().SetTextBkColor(col);
    GetListCtrl().SetRedraw(TRUE);

    //fill the view with 10 sample items
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {   
        CString csItem;
        csItem.Format(L"Item %d",i+1);

        GetListCtrl().InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_IMAGE,i,csItem,0,0,0,0);

        CString csItem2;
        csItem2.Format(L"Item2 %d",i+1);
        GetListCtrl().SetItem(i,1,LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_IMAGE,csItem2,1,0,0,0,0);
    }
}
```

It's really simple but I cannot get the result I want, and only the first column has images 
[image: wrong result]
I wanted that both columns had images, so the result should be like this
[image: expected result, edited picture with mspaint =)]

So what am I missing here? How can I correctly show the images also on the second column? 
any help is apreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: @ahmedsafan86: It was true more than 20 years ago with Windows 95. Even then you can use comctl version 4.70 and use this style. Starting from windows 98 the extended style is available for the developers without custom drawing

Comment: @ahmedsafan86, cha is right I'm not sure about the exact version that included this, but it is true that it was not available from the start of CListCtrl

Comment: you both are right, I was wrong, I didn't deal with the syle LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES before and also didn't read the question well and didn't see it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use ModifyStyleEx(). It is for the CWnd's extendended styles. For the CListCtrl specific styles use SetExtendedStyle(). Check this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/m6gAfnmf1FU)

Quote from the link above:

> The list of extended styles for the ModifyStyleEx() all start with a WS_EX_... and presumably change a bit in the Window struct via the SetWindowLong(...).
>   The SetExtendedStyle() method belongs to the CListCtrl in the List View and has style bits defined by LVS_EX_...  Since the controls extended style is 
>   sent via a SendMessage(...), the number of extended style bits is not 
>   limited to a single word and so can presumably exceed 32.